# Singleton instance or instance in every action call in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, singleton

This particular application is a suite of many small utilities, doing a specific job that is unlikely to overlap with each other.

So every utility has its own class and its own methods. More than 2 controller actions exist for every utility class. In every action i create a new instance of the utility class like this:

```
public PartialViewResult NullifiedInvoicesFix_List(string id)
{
    var _obj = new BgNullifiedInvoicesFix(string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ENTERBG"].ConnectionString, "CRPDTA"));
    ViewBag.F4211 = _obj.GetF4211List();
    return PartialView();
}
public PartialViewResult NullifiedInvoicesFix_Step1()
{
    var _obj = new BgNullifiedInvoicesFix(string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ENTERBG"].ConnectionString, "CRPDTA"));
    _obj.UpdateF74G4111();
    _obj.UpdateF4211();
    ViewBag.F4211Count = _obj.CountF4211();
    ViewBag.F74G4111Count = _obj.CountF74G4111();
    return PartialView();
}
```

Snippet of a utility class:

```
    public class BgNullifiedInvoicesFix
    {
        private IDbConnection _db;

        public BgNullifiedInvoicesFix(string serverConnection)
        {
            _db = new OleDbConnection(serverConnection);
        }
        public dynamic GetF4211List()
        {
            return this._db.Query<dynamic>(AppConstants.BG.NullifiedInvoicesFix.SelectF4211);
        }
}
```

Is it ok if i get a new instance in every call action?

Does the Garbage Collector takes care of these or i should go with singleton implementation in every utility class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok if i get a new instance in every call action?

Yes.

> Does the Garbage Collector takes care of these or i should go with
>   singleton implementation in every utility class?

The GC takes care of everything that falls out of scope which is the case here. So you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: thanks! so the only thing i have to do now is to implement DI in utility class in case something bad happens to DAPPER in the future. Correct?

Comment: Yes, DI will weaken the coupling between the different layers of your application. This in turn will make them more reusable and give you the possibility to replace one layer with another more easily.